# Different ways of importing Angular 2 components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I saw that there are 2 ways of importing on typescript the angular components files:

> import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
>
> import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

I understand that this ways are becuase of the way I add this into the package.json dependency.

like:

```
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.16",
```

or:

```
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

The question is:
which is the best way of adding Angular 2 to my project, and why?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it depends on the version of Angular2 you use:

- beta version: `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';`
- RC version: `import {Component} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Sounds good! i'm starting a new project, so probably i will use the RC version! thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Btw... how can i see the github repository for all the @angular parts? 
I'm assuming that for example @angular/platform-browser-dynamic is: https://github.com/angular/platform-browser-dynamic-builds
So basically everything on package.json maps to @angular2/*-builds

Comment: In fact, these modules are available as NPM modules so you can install them locally in your project and configure SystemJS to use them. See this doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change in the naming convention of angular packages since the beta that's why the new rc-4 and rc-5 versions packages start with `@angular` and these are the ones you should use.
The best way is to either use a tool like [Angular Cli](https://cli.angular.io/) , import manually from npm package by package or use ready seed projects that you can find all over github

Comment: can you recommend me a good seed project to start with? i mean with angular rc4 or rc5,. Actually, this looks like the best one for me : https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: Indeed this one is good, try out the angular cli also, it really speeds things up :)